# Express router uses different route when adding param

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have two routes

I'm trying to access /name and pass the name param. It hits the /name route when I have the endpoint as just /name with no parameter, but when I change it to '/name/:name' to get the param, it switches and starts to use the '/:id' route

```
router.get('/name/:name', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('called name',req.params.name )
  Project.findOne({name:req.params.name}).then(results => {
    res.json({"project": results})
  })
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('called id')
  Project.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).then(results => {
    res.json({"project": results})
  })
})
```

when I take away ':name' it uses the name route, but when I add it back it uses the Id.

Comment: Give the example routes. Like which url are you accessing and what is the result. That will clarify some things.

Comment: I'm trying to access /name and pass the name param. it hits the /name route when I have the endpoint as just /name with no parameter, but when I change it to '/name:name' to get the param, it switches and starts to use the '/:id' route

Answer (score 1):

I guess you misunderstood how routes work. Check out [this mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes#Route_parameters) for more information.

`/name/:name` will match any a route like `/name/.*` that means it will match anythyng if it has `/name/` as prefix, i.e `/name/xyz`.

`:name` is a **PLACEHOLDER**. Which means whatever you put after `/name/` it is accessible by the `req.params.name` variable.

Now for your example, when you are hitting `/name:name` it is not matching the `/name/.*` pattern so it goes to the next route. which is `/:id` means `/.*` which is effectively any route.